# Equivalence proof

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ be sequences with e.g.f $F(t)$ and $G(t)$ respectively. Show the equivalence of the following:
>
> 1. $$g_n=\sum^n_{k=0}{n\choose k}\ f_k$$
> 2. $$G(t)=F(t)e^{t}.$$

Attempt:

I am not sure how to do this. But for part $1$ I just assumed $2$ and got:

$$g_n=n!\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{f_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!}=\sum^n_{k=0}{n\choose k}f_k.$$

Comment: What do you mean "($f_n$) is a sequence with $F(t)$"?

Comment: What does egf mean? Something about generating functions I presume?

Comment: Do you know what the e.g.f of a sequence means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition
\begin{align*}
F(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f_n}{n!}\,t^n
&
G(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g_n}{n!}\,t^n
\end{align*}

First, assume 
$$
g_n=\sum^n_{k=0}{n\choose k}\ f_k
$$
Then the [Cauchy product of series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) gives
\begin{align*}
F(t)\,e^t
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f_n}{n!}\,t^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\,t^n\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f_k}{k!}t^k\frac{1}{(n-k)!}t^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f_k}{k!(n-k)!}t^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}f_k\, t^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}f_k\, t^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{g_n}{n!}\, t^n \\
&= G(t)
\end{align*}
Can you prove the converse?

Comment: I see, thank you very much!